# What does the billing address do in Amazon.com?

Tags: amazon

I noticed the billing address is different than the shipping address for orders off Amazon.com. When I asked what gets sent to the billing address they kept saying

> The billing address will reflect on the on line invoice which you have
>   the option to view on line or print from the website. A bill only be
>   sent to the billing address if an account requires payment from our
>   collections department.

So nothing gets sent to the billing address unless there's an outstanding balance? How does this even make sense since things are paid for by credit card, would  Amazon send you a bill if you hadn't paid off your credit card?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if you have a debit or credit card through Amazon.com, or another form of payment where they are handling the account, that's where the bill or notice would go if you are late on payments.

That address can also be used to verify that the owner of the card is the real owner of the card when they check with the bank or card issuer and compare against the billing address listed on the order. It's one factor in helping against fraud.

But most of the time nothing is sent there.

Comment: Amazon also likes to reset your default shipping address to the billing address for the card you last used. You need constant vigilance.   I remove all addresses except the one I ship to, and amazon hates it.

Answer (score 5):

The credit card company knows your billing address, and it is used for verification. For that credit card there is a direct relationship to the billing address.

For some transactions the credit card is not charged until the product is shipped. They will not charge you for the item until a back ordered item is available. You can also pre-order books, movies, computer games to make sure you get an anticipated item in the first wave. In instant transactions the check for a valid card is done during the order process, and a hold is placed on the amount of the purchase. In these delayed transactions they will use the billing info at the time or order fulfillment.

In some business transactions the billing address has zero relationship to the mailing address. The payment could be by credit card (personal or corporate) or by business account or invoice system.

Scenarios where shipping address doesn't equal billing address:

- You live in an apartment, and want a package sent to a place that can accept the box.
- It is a gift and want it sent directly to the recipient.
- It is your kids text books and want it sent to the college campus.
- You are out of town and want it sent to where you are.
- You want to hide it from somebody in your household.
- The student is using the parents credit card.

Comment: Lucky kids whose parents pay for everything